# Scrape javascript generated result with scrapy-splash

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to scrape the result generated by a javascript function when you introduce some acronym in a dictionary search box. This is the code I'm using:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashFormRequest


class SedomSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sedom-spider'
    url_s = 'https://www.sedom.es/diccionario/'

    formdata = {'sigla': 'AA'}

    def parse(self, response):
        return SplashFormRequest(
        url=self.url_s,
        formdata=self.formdata,
        callback=self.after_login
    )

    def after_login(self, response):
        print(response.body)
```

I obtain the html body, but the generated result (`<span id="resultado">...</span>`) I should see is not in it...

I've also tried:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest, SplashFormRequest


class SedomSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sedom-spider'
    url_s = 'https://www.sedom.es/diccionario/'

    formdata = {'sigla': 'AA'}

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(
            url=self.url_s,
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        yield SplashFormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata=self.formdata,
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
           print(response.body)
```

But then I get this error:

> ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: javascript:procesar()

I know scrapy-splash is well configured because I did this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvFC93vAB7U) and worked fine. I may have a misconception using this library because I've tried every solution I found and I'm not able to get it working...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found the solution. I post it here in case it is useful to someone.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashFormRequest


class SedomSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sedom-spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.sedom.es/diccionario/',]

    formdata = {'sigla': 'AA'}

    def parse(self, response):
        yield SplashFormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            url='https://www.sedom.es/diccionario/procesarBusquedaSigla.php',
            formdata=self.formdata,
            callback=self.parse_details,
            args={'wait': 5}
        )

    def parse_details(self, response):
        print(response.body)
```

The main problem was that I was not using the proper url inside `SplashFormRequest.from_response()`.